# Is there concurrency or is it just missing precision?

Tags: time, measurements, error-analysis

Imagine I measure the time of two balls hitting the ground. My stopwatch displays 5.5 seconds for both of them. Then I could say, that both balls hit the ground at the same time. But if I add a few more decimal places, the result is not the same anymore (lets say 5.50003 and 5.50007).

With this idea in mind, if I had a stopwatch, that could measure with an infinite precision. Would I be able to make two things happen at the **exact** same time? Or is there always an delay?

Comment: You can't ever measure anything exactly. Are you asking if two things can philosophically happen at the same time in spite of the inability to measure it? Because that just might be what it is: philosophy.

Comment: Kind of, because I cannot measure exactly (I think), can I be sure, that something is truely concurrrent?

Comment: IMO, that's philosophy if you can't even theoretically measure it (uncertainty principle), but I'm not a physicist. It also discounts that there are other possibilities too. Along with infinite, exact resolution is finite, exact resolution as well as fuzziness below which a certain level. In both time and space (which matters if you are trying to figure out when exactly something is "impacting" something else).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you assume that time is quantized, you can never have two events occur at the exact same time.

Comment: Sure you can. When the two events correspond to the same point as well. Consider two wave fronts intersecting an object in such a way they intersect at a point. That point in space corresponds to the time each wave front reaches that point. Two events, one point in space-time.  You just can't measure it to arbitrary accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You use one stopwatch. You observe the one watch and the two balls simultaneously. Your observation point is such that all distinctions on differences in path length for observations are to be removed.

In other words, you make a perfect, simultaneous measurement for two events occurring at two locations in space using one recording device.

What you record is a real difference between the two events. The precision with your first watch is insufficient to record the difference. The precision in your second watch is sufficient.

Following the above, you are limited by measurement precision.

When you have a measurement device and measurement method that are infinitely precise, you can do whatever you want. You could design a perfect experiment to have the events occur at precisely the same time. How? By defining the precision limits in each step in the experiment.

At some point, you may come to realize that two objects cannot occupy exactly (with infinite precision) the same spatial region at exactly (with infinite precision) the same time. You probably should realize this already before you even start doing any experiments that should have infinite precision in their events and measurements.